# Flask-SQLAlchemy how to manage one session/transaction in multiple requests

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

From what I have already learned, the Database sessions isolated in the request threads - I mean, when user send request to the Flask server, then the route function create session, manipulate the database and then commit/rollback database (which ends session). I would like to know how to manipulate one session with multiple requests. Something like:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


@app.route("/create_session")
def create_session():
    session = db.session        # create session
    ...
    return response


@app.route("/query")
def query():
    ...                         # perform some operations with the session
    return response


@app.route("/end_session")
def end_session():
    session.commit()            # commit session
    ...
    return response
```

where:

- First I am calling the request to the '/create_session' route to create session
- Then I am calling the request to the '/query' route to do some operations with session
- On the end I am calling the request to the '/end_session' route to end session

All routes manage only one, shared transaction.
Thanks for any response!

Comment: It's possible to do this, but it isn't a good idea.  The SQLAlchemy engine maintains a pool of connections which are checked out when a session is opened and returned once the session is closed.  If you keep a session open across requests you will need a bigger connection pool.  Moreover, what if the visitor doesn't visit end session?

Comment: It is just project-specific case. I just want to have two servers when one (Server A) communicate with DB and the second one (server B) communicate with the first one and based on the set of routes I would like to create the entire transaction.

In the case of visitor doesn't visiting the end session I would like to use some kind of timeout system and just rollback all the changes. 

So if it is possible then how could I achieve this? :)

Comment: If I were to do this I'd probably start by devising a scope function to use with scoped_session that lets me map requests to sessions - see [Using Custom Created Scopes](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/contextual.html#using-custom-created-scopes).  (You'd do `db = SQLAlchemy(app, session_options={'scopefunc': myfunc})`  in Flask SQLAlchemy).  But I would strongly recommend trying to find an architecture that doesn't require this.